# Why the $2.99 minimum price for apps

Tags: application-development

According to http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/ Apps can only be published at a $2.99 minimum price, which seems to include the ubuntu touch apps.

99% of the apps I have purchased on android are $0.99
If Ubuntu goes ahead with this, isn't it going to:

1) exclude a lot of developers/apps.

2) or Force developers to push up the price, so that you end up paying 3x as much for the same product.

3) or give the app away free but force more adds or in game/app purchases which are the bane of the app world.

Comment: To me that's clearly about the desktop Software Center. 1)I don't see how that minimum would exclude anyone? specially developers they would get more revenue how is that *bad*. 2) I don't understand how that minimum would increase the price, at all. 3)I still don't understand your reasoning behind this, if you're getting the app for **free** how is the dev. supposed to make a living out of it?. Not all people donate, and *Ads* can be placed to not be intrusive.

Comment: http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/ "We've adopted QML at the heart of a set of technologies to bring the Ubuntu experience to mobile devices" seems to indicate this is more than just the desktop 

1)Simple apps cannot expect to sell for the same price as better quality apps. That's like pushing a LG L3 into the Samsung nexus price range and expecting them to compete. 

2)If its 0.99 on Google play, they will have to charge 2,99 on the Ubuntu store. That's a 200% increase for the same product.

Comment: 3)If you cannot compete with the 2.99 apps, you will be forced to either charge that anyway and risk no one buying your app, or give it away free and include adds or in app purchases.

Comment: Then there's a problem with the Publish page making no reference to mobile apps. 1) 2) and 3) You (as a dev.) can't expect competition to give you a break if your app is not up to the task you (as a dev.) should improve it and make it worth 2.99, I for one would rather have 1000 quality apps than 10,000 simple ones. You have to make your app worth that much.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Commercial Software FAQ](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/commercial-software-faqs/):

> **What is the minimum price I can charge for software?**
>
> The minimum price for applications is 2.99 USD. The transaction fee we charge has to off-set the credit card charges, bank charges and fraud detection that takes place within the payment platform. By enforcing a minimum price we ensure that processing transactions doesn’t cost more than the transaction fee. We intend to lower the minimum price over time.

Comment: That makes sense.